# Send a post with jQuery from a https page to a https

Tags: php, jquery, https

My script had been always worked but then after the newer Chrome update, it stopped working.

I have a page where my clients can log in. This page is protected with ssl.
The form is submit by jQuery

```
$.post('pierre_registrar.php', {bean_name: usuario, bean_password: senha, bean_repassword: senha, bean_day: dia, bean_month: mes, bean_year: ano, bean_email: email, inscription: 'sim', tos: tos}, function(resposta) { alert(resposta); }));
```

pierre_registrar.php will verify the form and send a answer.

In the javascript console shows: 
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/#registration' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.com/pierre_registrar.php'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

and pierre_registrar.php is block by the chrome.

What should i do? Sorry for my english, I m not good at it.

Comment: I can't see why a post request to a relative url from a https page would be made using http. Are you using url rewriting and what does the form and the rest of you javascript look like?

Comment: @jeroen Im using url rewriting but not over pierre_registrar.php or any script linked to the login form.

Comment: @jeroen well i finally got why. On my core.php there was a redirect to http when is not in the login page. So i fixed. Thanks jeroen you made me connect the dots lol